# Spring AOP pointcut expression excluding a particular return type or argument

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-aspects

```
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(..)) ", returning = "result")
public void repo(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    // ... 
}
```

This pointcut covers all save or update operations irrespective of the argument passed or return type but I want to exclude just xyz.class in arguments or return type. How is that possible?
I can not mention all save operations because there are total 50+ models but I want only 48 of them to be covered.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.yash.arci.repository.*.save(*))")
public void allrepository() {
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.yash.arci.repository.AuditRepository.save(*))")
public void auditrepository() {
}

@Before(value = "allrepository() && !auditrepository()")
public void repo(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
}
```

This is the alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You declare included and excluded method signatures and combine them like this

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(..))")
public void any() {
}

@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(MyClass1))" +
        " || execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(MyClass2))")
public void excluded() {
}

@AfterReturning(value = "any() && !excluded()", returning = "result")
public void repo(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is not working. It's not considering the excluded condition.
 (And MyClass1 and MyClass2 need to have fully classified name else giving exceptions.)

Comment: I have got the solution.
@Pointcut("execution(* com.arci.repository.*.save(*))")
 public void allrepository() {
 }

 @Pointcut("execution(* com.arci.repository.AuditRepository.save(*))")
 public void auditrepository() {
 }

 @Before(value = "allrepository() && !auditrepository()")
 public void repo(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
}

Comment: @Priyam nice! I'm glad that I was able to give you correct direction :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do keeping in mind the [erasure of a type](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/generics-inAspectJ5.html), is just return from the method without doing anything, if the arg type is XYZ.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository+.save(..))")
  public void savePointCut() {
    // savePointCut
  }

  @AfterReturning(value = "savePointCut()", returning = "result")
  public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
    if (joinPoint.getArgs()[0] instanceof XYZ) return;
    logger.info("AfterReturning :[{}]", joinPoint.getArgs());
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is also an alternate way if I want to filter out just few classes. Fortunately I have so far just classes to filter out. Anyway thanks for this. :)